# Spark task fails to write rows into ORC table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geospark

I run the following code for a spatial join on geometry fields:

```
 val coverage = DimCoverageReader.apply(spark, params)
    coverage.createOrReplaceTempView("dim_coverage")

    val uniqueGeometries = spark.table(params.UniqueGeometriesTable)
    uniqueGeometries.createOrReplaceTempView("unique_geometries")


    spark
      .sql(
        """select a.*, b.lac, b.cell_id
          |from unique_geometries as a, dim_coverage as b
          |where ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromWKT(a.geo_wkt), ST_GeomFromWKT(b.geo_wkt))
          |""".stripMargin)
```

The resulting dataframe is later saved into ORC table:

```
Stage(spark,params).write
          .format("orc")
          .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .saveAsTable(params.IntersectGeometriesTable)
```

I get this error during execution:
*org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows*

```
    0/10/30 17:37:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 205.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 1219)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column has wrong number of index entries found: 320 expected: 800
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$TreeWriter.writeStripe(WriterImpl.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$StructTreeWriter.writeStripe(WriterImpl.java:1742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.flushStripe(WriterImpl.java:2133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.checkMemory(WriterImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.MemoryManager.notifyWriters(MemoryManager.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.MemoryManager.addedRow(MemoryManager.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.addRow(WriterImpl.java:2413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcOutputFormat.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcOutputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcOutputWriter.write(OrcFileFormat.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:259)
    ... 8 more
```

What is the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this works fine with `format('parquet')` my guess is that you have some sort of struct type or formatting issue. Can you add the `printSchema` for your DF?